# creating instances of classes in context of parent child relation ship-java

Tags: java

i am trying to understand how instances of class or subclass are created in parent/child context.Take a look at this code:

```
class A  {
    public void methodl() { //class "A" method caled } 
}  
class B extends A  {  
    public void methodl() { //class "B" method caled } 
}  
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String args[])  {  
        //case 1  
        A a=new A();  
        a.method1();  
        //case 2  
        B b=new B();  
        b.method1();  
        //case 3  
        A a=new B();  
        a.method1();  
        //case 4  
        B b=new A();  
        b.method1();  
    } 
}
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Any chance you could fix your indentation?

Comment: I suggest you ask a question so we can give you an answer.  I suggest you try stepping through your code in a debugger to see which method is called.  BTW: case 4 won't compile. I suggest you only consider cases which compile.

Comment: very sorry for the inconveince actually i was not having IDE/jdk right now.wel i would try to be more specific from next time.

Comment: What is a relation ship? Is it some kind of boat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String args[])  {  
        //case 1  
        A a=new A();  
        a.method1();
```

In case 1, a is a reference to an A object, and the call will be to A's method1.

```
        //case 2  
        B b=new B();  
        b.method1();
```

In case 2, b is a reference to a B object, and the call will be to B's method1.

```
        //case 3  
        A a=new B();  
        a.method1();
```

In case 3, a is a reference to a B object, even though it could reference any A object and the call will be to B's method1.

Actually, as it sits, it won't compile, because you're declaring the variable a again in a scope where it's already defined.

```
        //case 4  
        B b=new A();  
        b.method1();
```

Case 4 makes no sense, and will not compile.

```
    } 
}
```